# И снова МАТРИЦЫ и кому они нужны?

Tags: разработка-игр, графика, геометрия, матрицы, gpu

Погружаюсь в дебри компьютерной графики в частности 3D, и наткнулся на матрицы. Вообщем то наткнулся уже давно, но вот вопросы начали возникать только сейчас.
Матрица в памяти это объект NxM, в современной 3D графике 4x4 и причём ещё и 32 бита занимают float'ы всякие то есть их размер 4*4*32 = 512 бит и зачем они нам такие нужны? ну да ладно даже столько не жалко, так это ведь говорят только на одну операцию да ещё и 40% нулями заполнена. А у этой самой 3D графики самая слабая точка, как и у CPU - это пропускная способность памяти и шины!!! Так а зачем матрицы, если к примеру на гпу можно отправить только XYZ сдвига и сказать сложи? зачем столько пустого места в матрицах?

К примеру у нас есть
`Vec3 Позиция, Поворот, Масштаб` - это вектора которые служат для трансформации вертексов, и при этом я имею методы `Move(Vec3 B){ X += B.X ...}; Rotate(Vec3 B){ X += cosA ... } и Scale(){...(не помню)};` они выполняют те же операции что были бы выполнены над матрицами только принимают по три вектора и вычисления проводятся над ними, а не над всей матрицей при этом уменьшается количество проводимых операций. Так зачем хранить эти же данные в массивах 4x4? http://www.gamedev.ru/code/articles/faq_matrix_quat в низу страницы нечто подобное

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41407/discussion-on-question-by----------).